# No output of ps and netstat on Ubuntu 22.04 server

Tags: bash

It just happened that ps and netstat output nothing.
How can I make it print on console?
Environment:

```
root@server3-8x64:~# lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

root@server3-8x64:~# uname -a

Linux server3-8x64 5.4.0-162-generic #179-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 14 08:51:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@server3-8x64:~#
```

symptoms:

1. Try ps -x or ps -w or netstat -aln but nothing is shown
2. If enter sh and both work well.
3. If write a script and exeucte it, it has output

   ```
   root@server3-8x64:~# cat test.sh

   #!/bin/bash

   ps -x
   ```
4. I had tried to reinstall ps by below command but it does not work

   ```
   apt-get install --reinstall procps
   ```
5. I had tried to reboot ubuntu server but it does not work

Comment: Try typing `stty sane`, and then try your commands again.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried the command but it does not work.

Comment: If the problem is limited to *interactive*, *bash* shells (not scripts or interactive sh shells) then it is likely some configuration issue, such as having aliased `ps` and `netstat` to something else in your .bashrc or .bash_aliases file. What does `type -a ps` return?

Comment: Your recent change to `~/.bashrc` probably broke it. Debug with `bash -x ~/.bashrc` from a working environment.

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks your great help. The .bashrc is rewrited with unkonwn reason and alias 'ps=printf ""'. I copied a correct .bashrc from other server and this issue is resolved.